# Android camera - onPictureTaken not called (Using GCM)

Tags: java, android, camera, google-cloud-messaging

I start programming an Android-Application with Google Cloud Messaging. When a Message from GCM received, i want to take a Picture with the Front-Camera.
I can send my message, receive it and start to take the picture. All looks fine, but onPictureTaken() did never called every time ... 
Only when i set a breaking point, it works correctly and makes the picture and save it, when no breakpoint is set or i don't use the debugger, it didn't work..

It looks like a runtime-problem ..

I looked about solutions, but i didn't find anything useful informations ..

PLEASE HELP ME!

EDIT:
**When i exec "cam = Camera.open(CamID)" in Activity Create it works successfully for first photo in the intentservice... it looks like the Camera isn't correctly initialized when i call cam.takepicture();
Anyone have ideas ?**

```
 @Override
protected void onMessage(final Context context, Intent msg) 
{
    // Handle the message.
     final String message = msg.getStringExtra("message");

     Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "onMessage called:" + message);

     Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
     h.post(new Runnable()
     {

          public void run() 
          {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "Handler started");
              Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              TakePicture();
          }         
      });        
}

Camera camera;
int cameraId = 0;

public void TakePicture()
{


    try 
    {
        // do we have a camera?
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) 
        {
            Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "No Camera");
            Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
        else 
        {
            cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId < 0) 
            {
                Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "No front camera found!");
                Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
            else 
            {
            try
                {

                    if (camera != null)
                    {
                        Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "camera release");
                        camera.release();
                    }

                    camera = Camera.open(cameraId);    
                    camera.startPreview(); 
                    Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "Take Picture ...");
                    camera.takePicture(null, null, new PhotoHandler(this));
                    Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "Picture successfully taken ..");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "camera takepicture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } 
                }

            }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

private int findFrontFacingCamera() 
{
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) 
    {
        CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) 
        {
            Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "Camera found");
            cameraId = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return cameraId;
}
```

**And this is my PhotoHandler class:**

```
package com.example.messenger;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback 
{

    private final Context context;

    public PhotoHandler(Context context) 
    {
        Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "PhotoHandler constructor called");
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
    {

        Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "onPictureTaken called");
        Toast.makeText(context, "OnPictureTaken", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        File pictureFileDir = getDir();

        if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) 
        {
            Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "Can't create directory to save image.");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
        String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";

        String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

        File pictureFile = new File(filename);

        try 
        {
            Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "Begin Fileoutputstream");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "Image saved: " + photoFile);
        } catch (Exception error) {
            Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "File" + filename + "not saved: "
                    + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        Log.d(konstanten.DEBUG_PHOTO, "onTakePicture end");
    }

    private File getDir() 
    {
        File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        return new File(sdDir, konstanten.AppName);
    }
}
```

**LogCat-Output (For DEBUG_PHOTO-Tag):**

`06-25 16:41:37.831: D/PHOTO-HANDLER(16917): onMessage called:Hello World!
06-25 16:41:37.841: D/PHOTO-HANDLER(16917): Handler started
06-25 16:41:37.876: D/PHOTO-HANDLER(16917): Camera found
06-25 16:41:38.886: D/PHOTO-HANDLER(16917): Take Picture ...
06-25 16:41:38.911: D/PHOTO-HANDLER(16917): PhotoHandler constructor called
06-25 16:41:39.021: D/PHOTO-HANDLER(16917): Picture successfully taken ..`

Comment: when you say it doesn't work, can you tell us which toast is called on which error path? otherwise you can track the path of the error with system.out.println or log.e, as far i can see, there are no logical errors

Comment: I updated my question.
You see: No error and onPictureTaken didn't called...

Comment: By the book, you should call `Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Holder)` before you can `startPreview()`. Even if your device does not enforce this requirement, other devices will not work without preview surface (or texture).